# Prove about weak convergence in $C[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis

I have to prove that **(1)** if a function sequence $(f_n) \subset C[0,1]$ is weakly convergent to $f\in C[0,1]$ then $f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ for any $x \in [0,1]$. I have also to **(2)** show, that pointwise convergence of $(f_n) \subset C[0,1]$ does not imply weak convergence.

**My attempt:**

**(1)** Let $(f_n) \subset C[0,1]$ be a sequence that is weakly convergence to $f\in C[0,1]$.We have:
$$\forall \phi \in B(C[0,1],\mathbb{K}): |\phi f_n(x)-\phi f(x)|\rightarrow 0 \:\:\:\: \forall x\in[0,1]$$
Now take $\theta : f \rightarrow f(x)$ Obviously:
$$\theta \in B(C[0,1],\mathbb{K})$$

we have:

$$|f_n(x)- f(x)| \rightarrow 0$$

**(2)** I consider the functional:
$$\alpha(f)=\int_0^1f(t)dt$$ but I can't think of any sequence $(f_n)$ which is pointwise convergent to some $f$ and $| \alpha(f_n-f)|$ does not go to $0$. Any help?

Comment: What is $Y$ here?

Comment: (2) Consider the sequence $$f_n (t) =\begin{cases} 0 \mbox{ if }  0\leq t<\frac{1}{n+1} \\ n^{100} \left(t-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(t-\frac{1}{n+1}\right) \mbox{ if } \frac{1}{n+1} <t<\frac{1}{n} \\ 0 \mbox{ if } \frac{1}{n} \leq t\leq 1\end{cases} $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) You only know the convergence $\phi(f_n) \rightarrow \phi(f)$ for bounded linear functionals $\phi$, not for arbitrary linear maps $\phi \in B(C([0,1]), Y)$ (and, as Daniel Fischer points out: What is $Y$?).

Convince yourself that the linear(!), bounded(!) functional $\phi_x(f) := f(x)$ does the job.

(2) Try something like $f_n = n \cdot \chi_{(0, 1/n)}$. Of course, you have to modify the idea to make it a continuous function.

Comment: $Y=\mathbb{R}$, and now what is wrong with part (1)? I will try (2) as you suggested

Comment: The problem with part (1) is that you never defined $\phi(f)$ (i.e. you do not state your choice of $\phi$). At least it is not clear to me what you $\phi$ is.

Comment: $\phi(f)$ is just a linear and continuous functional on $C[0,1]$ so  $\phi \in B(C[0,1],\mathbb{K})$

Comment: That is exactly the problem. You have to choose $\phi : C([0,1]) \rightarrow \mathbb{K}, f \mapsto f(x)$. (Why is that continuous)? Consider for example the space $L^1([0,1])$. Here, weak convergence does not(!) imply pointwise convergence. Why is that?

Comment: Ok I see now. From definition of weak convergence I have $\forall \phi \in B(C[0,1],\mathbb{K}): |\phi f_n(x)-\phi f(x)|\rightarrow 0 \:\:\:\: \forall x\in[0,1]$ but I have to consider specific $\phi$s as you mentioned. $f\rightarrow f(x)$ is continuous because it can be bounded by supremum with functional norm 1

Comment: I edited (1), Now going for (2)

Comment: I have no idea about (2) ;/

Comment: Just make the "rectangle" with height $n$ into a "triangle" so that the triangle has height $\sim 2n$ and is located between $0$ and $2/n$ (i.e. rise with slope $\sim n^2$ and fall with slope $\sim n^2$), or something like that. E.g. $f(x) = n^2x$ for $x \in [0,1/n]$, $f(x) = n^2 (2/n -x)$ for $x \in [1/n, 2/n]$

Comment: but to which function it is pointwise covnergent? to f=0?

Comment: Yes, because $f_n(0)=0$ and for $x \in (0,1]$ we have $2/n < x$ for $n \geq n_0(x)$ and hence also $f_n(x) =0$ for $n \geq n_0(x)$.